# Does this reliably work in IE8?

Tags: css, media-queries, ie8-compatibility-mode, ie-developer-tools

For media queries, does this work well in IE8?

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

I don't have any machine or VM with IE8 to test it.  I have tested it in IE9 using IE8 compatibility mode.  It seems to work until I refresh the page.  Then the media queries don't work anymore.

The JS file is from Google http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/ and enables media query functionality for older browsers.

Comment: I'm not sure if I totally understand the question, but for me this has been a very useful resource to check compatibility, so if it helps.... http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

Comment: Need to actually see it in action.  I can verify what "should" work in something all day long.  Seeing it is believing it.

Comment: If you need a VM to test, you can get one from http://modern.ie/, or you can also get a 3 month browserstack subscription too.

Comment: @david, I think that is the answer.  Can you post it?  Unfortunately, to do any testing you have to eventually buy a browserstack subscription.

Comment: The browserstack subscription is on the modern.ie website.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Browserstack has its own subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works on IE8. But the best approach would be to provide a fallback for all browsers that don't support mediaqueries.

To achieve it, you need Modernizr with MQ test and yepnope:

- http://modernizr.com/download/#-shiv-mq-cssclasses-teststyles-load

(this bundle also comes with html5shiv, useful if you're using HTML5)

After including it in your `<head>` section, test mqs and load the fallback conditionally:

```
Modernizr.load([
    { test : Modernizr.mediaqueries , nope :'css3-mediaqueries.js' }
]);
```